# How to solve eth_getFilterChanges looping when deploying with truffle (parity)?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, parity, truffle-migration

I am using truffle migrate and I get some kind of loop which just endlessly prints out eth_getFilterChanges. How can this be solved?

I have used this truffle.js

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8540,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gas: 4699999,
      from: "0x004ec07d2329997267ec62b4166639513386f32e" 
    }
  }
};
```

I used the DemoPoA setup at parity. I did a geth attach and it seems coinbase has a balance of zero.

```
   > ]
 <   [
 <     {
 <       "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <       "result": [],
 <       "id": 23
 <     }
 <   ]
   > [
   >   {
   >     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >     "id": 24,
   >     "method": "eth_getFilterChanges",
   >     "params": [
   >       "0x7"
   >     ]
   >   }
   > ]
 <   [
 <     {
 <       "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <       "result": [],
 <       "id": 24
 <     }
 <   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

npm uninstall -g truffle
npm install -g truffle